# spring-cloud-stream-test-binder OutputChannel subscription does not get invoked

Tags: spring-boot, testing, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a use case similar to the one mentioned here: [Spring Cloud Stream test-binder OutputDestination does not consume events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74981412/spring-cloud-stream-test-binder-outputdestination-does-not-consume-events)

I need to validate values in messages produced by the application. This was possible in older versions of Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder, using `MessageCollector`.

According to comments on the stackoverflow post mentioned above, I tried using `SubscribableChannel` to store the published/consumed messages in a queue for validation. But this seems to work only for `InputChannel`s (captures messages consumed by the application) and not for `OutputChannel`s (capture messages produced by the application).

Here's the code from my test app:

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>airplane</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>airplane</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-binder</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4-M1-groovy-4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.4-M1-groovy-4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-binder</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

AirplaneApplication.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class AirplaneApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AirplaneApplication.class, args);
    }

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AirplaneApplication.class);

    @Bean("ArrivalEvent")
    public Consumer<Message<ArrivalEvent>> arrivalEventConsumer() {
        return msg -> {
            logger.info("ArrivalEvent consumed: {}", msg.getPayload());
        };
    }

    @Bean("LandEvent")
    public Function<Message<LandEvent>, Message<ArrivalEvent>> landEventProcessor() {
        return landEventMessage -> {
            ArrivalEvent arrivalEvent = new ArrivalEvent(landEventMessage.getPayload().getFlightId()+"-flight", landEventMessage.getPayload().getCurrentAirport());
            logger.info("Publishing ArrivalEvent: {}", arrivalEvent);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(arrivalEvent)
                    .setHeader("Type", ArrivalEvent.class.getSimpleName())
                    .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "landEventProcessor-out-0")
                    .build();
        };
    }

    @Bean("FlightEvent")
    public Function<Message<FlightEvent>, Message<LandEvent>> flightEventProcessor() {
        return flightEventMessage -> {
            LandEvent landEvent = new LandEvent(flightEventMessage.getPayload().getFlightId()+"-flight", flightEventMessage.getPayload().getCurrentAirport());
            logger.info("Publishing LandEvent: {}", landEvent);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(landEvent)
                    .setHeader("Type", LandEvent.class.getSimpleName())
                    .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "flightEventProcessor-out-0")
                    .build();
        };
    }

    @Bean("PlaneEvent")
    public Function<Message<PlaneEvent>, Message<FlightEvent>> planeEventProcessor() {
        return planeEventMessage -> {
            FlightEvent flightEvent = new FlightEvent(planeEventMessage.getPayload().getPlaneId()+"-flight", planeEventMessage.getPayload().getCurrentAirport());
            logger.info("Publishing Flight: {}", flightEvent);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(flightEvent)
                    .setHeader("Type", FlightEvent.class.getSimpleName())
                    .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "planeEventProcessor-out-0")
                    .build();
        };
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=airplane
server.port=8095

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.planeEventProducer-out-0.destination=plane-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.planeEventProcessor-out-0.destination=flight-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.flightEventProcessor-out-0.destination=land-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.landEventProcessor-out-0.destination=arrival-events

spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings=replayProducer;planeEventProducer;planeEventProcessor;flightEventProcessor;landEventProcessor

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.functionRouter-in-0.destination=plane-events,flight-events,land-events,arrival-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.functionRouter-in-0.group=airplane
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.functionRouter-in-0.consumer.concurrency=8

spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=functionRouter;PlaneEvent;FlightEvent;LandEvent
spring.cloud.stream.function.routing.enabled=true
spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=headers['Type']
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.replication-factor=1
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.min-partition-count=8
```

TestUtil.groovy

```
class TestUtil {
    static Map<String, SubscribableChannel> getInputChannels(InputDestination inputDestination) {
        Field chField = ReflectionUtils.findField(InputDestination.class, "channels")
        chField.setAccessible(true);
        List<SubscribableChannel> channels = chField.get(inputDestination) as List<SubscribableChannel>
        return channels.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> getChannelName(x).replace(".destination", ""), x -> x))
    }

    static Map<String, SubscribableChannel> getOutputChannels(OutputDestination outputDestination) {
        Field chField = ReflectionUtils.findField(OutputDestination.class, "channels")
        chField.setAccessible(true);
        List<SubscribableChannel> channels = chField.get(outputDestination) as List<SubscribableChannel>
        return channels.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> getChannelName(x).replace(".destination", ""), x -> x))
    }

    static String getChannelName(SubscribableChannel ch) {
        Field chNameField = ReflectionUtils.findField(PublishSubscribeChannel.class, "fullChannelName")
        chNameField.setAccessible(true)
        try {
            return chNameField.get(ch) as String
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.err.println(e)
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

SampleTest.groovy

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [AirplaneApplication.class])
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Stepwise
@Title("Sample Test")
class SampleTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    StreamBridge streamBridge

    @Autowired
    OutputDestination outputDestination

    @Autowired
    InputDestination inputDestination

    class TestState {
        Map<String, SubscribableChannel> inputChannels
        Map<String, SubscribableChannel> outputChannels

        Map<String, Queue<Object>> inputMessages
        Map<String, Queue<Object>> outputMessages
    }

    TestState testState = new TestState()

    def initTestState(InputDestination inDest, OutputDestination outDest) {
        def inputChannels = TestUtil.getInputChannels(inDest)
        def outputChannels = TestUtil.getOutputChannels(outDest)
        getTestState().setInputChannels(inputChannels)
        getTestState().setOutputChannels(outputChannels)
        getTestState().setInputMessages(new HashMap<String, Queue<Object>>())
        getTestState().setOutputMessages(new HashMap<String, Queue<Object>>())

        getTestState().getInputChannels().keySet()
                .forEach(channelName -> getTestState().getInputMessages().put(channelName, new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>()))
        getTestState().getInputChannels().entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(inputChannelEntry -> {
                    def subscribableChannel = inputChannelEntry.getValue()
                    def channelName = inputChannelEntry.getKey()
                    subscribableChannel.subscribe(m -> { // add debug point 1 here
                        getTestState().getInputMessages().get(channelName).add(m)
                    })
                })

        getTestState().getOutputChannels().keySet()
                .forEach(channelName -> getTestState().getOutputMessages().put(channelName, new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>()))
        getTestState().getOutputChannels().entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(outputChannelEntry -> { // add debug point 2 here
                    def subscribableChannel = outputChannelEntry.getValue()
                    def channelName = outputChannelEntry.getKey()
                    subscribableChannel.subscribe(m -> {
                        getTestState().getOutputMessages().get(channelName).add(m)
                    })
                })
    }

    def "Sample Test"() {
        given: "A plane event is created"
        initTestState(inputDestination, outputDestination)

        when: "Plane Event is processed"
        Message<PlaneEvent> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(new PlaneEvent(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "CITY"))
                .setHeader("Type", PlaneEvent.class.getSimpleName())
        .build()
        streamBridge.send("functionRouter-in-0", message)

        then: "Flight event is raised"
//        def flightEventPayload = getTestState().getOutputMessages().get("flightEventProcessor")
        System.out.println() // add debug point 3 here
    }
}
```

As shown in the above snippet (`SampleTest.groovy`), I added 3 debug points to check if the `OutputChannel` subscribe works, and execution never stopped at `debug point 2`. And at `debug point 3` the output message queues are empty, but there are messages in the input message queues.

The test itself works, i.e. messages are published and consumed as expected (validated by logging).

```
2023-04-19T11:16:18.178+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] c.example.airplane.AirplaneApplication   : Publishing Flight: FlightEvent(flightId=556150f2-22d5-42c7-b88f-3a2373d12ea4-flight, currentAirport=CITY)
2023-04-19T11:16:18.183+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'unknown.channel.name' has 1 subscriber(s).
2023-04-19T11:16:18.184+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] figuration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1 : Output message is sent to 'planeEventProcessor-out-0' destination
2023-04-19T11:16:18.198+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.context.config.RoutingFunction   : Resolved function from provided [routing-expression]  headers['Type']
2023-04-19T11:16:18.199+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] c.example.airplane.AirplaneApplication   : Publishing LandEvent: LandEvent(flightId=556150f2-22d5-42c7-b88f-3a2373d12ea4-flight-flight, currentAirport=CITY)
2023-04-19T11:16:18.200+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'unknown.channel.name' has 1 subscriber(s).
2023-04-19T11:16:18.201+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] figuration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1 : Output message is sent to 'flightEventProcessor-out-0' destination
2023-04-19T11:16:18.201+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.context.config.RoutingFunction   : Resolved function from provided [routing-expression]  headers['Type']
2023-04-19T11:16:18.204+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] c.example.airplane.AirplaneApplication   : Publishing ArrivalEvent: ArrivalEvent(flightId=556150f2-22d5-42c7-b88f-3a2373d12ea4-flight-flight-flight, currentAirport=CITY)
2023-04-19T11:16:18.206+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'unknown.channel.name' has 1 subscriber(s).
2023-04-19T11:16:18.206+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] figuration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1 : Output message is sent to 'landEventProcessor-out-0' destination
2023-04-19T11:16:18.207+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.context.config.RoutingFunction   : Resolved function from provided [routing-expression]  headers['Type']
2023-04-19T11:16:18.208+05:30  INFO 12084 --- [           main] c.example.airplane.AirplaneApplication   : ArrivalEvent consumed: ArrivalEvent(flightId=556150f2-22d5-42c7-b88f-3a2373d12ea4-flight-flight-flight, currentAirport=CITY)
```

Am I missing something, or is there a different way of getting it to work?

If it helps, here's my test app: https://github.com/KarthikRIyer/spring-cloud-stream-function-routing

**EDIT 1:**

I made a few changes after which I started getting some messages in the output channel subscriber:

Instead of creating separate producer bindings for each processor/function I specified destinations for output channels for the processor like so:

```
# spring.cloud.stream.bindings.planeEventProcessor-out-0.destination=flight-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.PlaneEvent-out-0.destination=flight-events

# spring.cloud.stream.bindings.flightEventProcessor-out-0.destination=land-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.FlightEvent-out-0.destination=land-events

# spring.cloud.stream.bindings.landEventProcessor-out-0.destination=arrival-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.LandEvent-out-0.destination=arrival-events
```

And used them in `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` like so:

```java
@Bean("PlaneEvent")
    public Function<Message<PlaneEvent>, Message<FlightEvent>> planeEventProcessor() {
        return planeEventMessage -> {
            FlightEvent flightEvent = new FlightEvent(planeEventMessage.getPayload().getPlaneId()+"-flight", planeEventMessage.getPayload().getCurrentAirport());
            logger.info("Publishing Flight: {}", flightEvent);
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(flightEvent)
                    .setHeader("Type", FlightEvent.class.getSimpleName())
//                  .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "planeEventProcessor-out-0")
                    .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "PlaneEvent-out-0")
                    .build();
        };
    }
```

At the same time I changed the test to publish the workflow starter message through `planeEventProducer-out-0` channel which does not have a bean definition, but is specified in the properties `spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings=planeEventProducer;`.

```java
streamBridge.send("planeEventProducer-out-0", message)
```

This is what I see in the debugger now:

[image]

There is no message in the `planeEventProducer` channel. Why is that?

Comment: If you expect your Kafka environment to get involved in the test, that will not work. Test binder strictly works on in-memory-based Spring Integration channels.

Comment: If you intend to write a full integration test, then you might want to look into `EmbeddedKafka` and test that way and use the test binder.

Comment: See this doc section we added recently: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/4.0.3-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_special_note_on_mixing_test_binder_and_regular_middleware_binder_for_testing

Comment: Yes, I understand that the test binder works on in-memory-based channels, and that is what I want to do. The only problem I'm facing is that I am unable to verify messages produced by the application, as I was able to with MessageCollector in earlier versions of the test binder. In the workaround I tried to implement, I do not see the output channel subscriber getting called.

Comment: I do see that you have multiple bindings. `OutputDestination` has `receive(long timeout, String bindingName)` method. I dont see you invoking it. What do you expect? Consider looking at how we're using it - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/core/spring-cloud-stream-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/ImplicitFunctionBindingTests.java

Comment: `outputDestination.receive()` gives me null. For eg, when the app publishes FlightEvent, flightEventProcessor() will consume this event, and publish LandEvent. When my app has consumers for a published message, I am unable to receive it in the outputDestination. My expectation is that `subscribableChannel.subscribe(m -> { ...` this is called for output channels so that I can store these messages in a queue for validation.

Comment: I tried a few more things, and made an edit to the question. Could you please check?